# Firestore with Flutter

Tags: flutter

I got this warning every time I try to install firestore

WARNING: This version of cloud_firestore will break your Android build if it or its dependencies aren't compatible with AndroidX.
         See https://goo .gl/CP92wY for more information on the problem and how to fix it.
         This warning prints for all Android build failures. The real root cause of the error may be unrelated.

---

also I use cloud_firestore without detecting version number.

Comment: Try to downgrade your cloud_firestore plugin verison to 0.8.2+1 or less

Comment: problem still existed, thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to use Firestore with firebase_auth or 
you are getting an error like *'Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file'*

You should enable multidex:

If your minSdkVersion is set to 21 or higher, all you need to do is set multiDexEnabled to true in your module-level build.gradle

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 21 
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}
```

for further information : https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

Comment: I also did that, but every time I try a solution, another problem occurred, I hope your answer helps others. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I also had this error.  I fixed it by following these steps:

1. Close all device emulators.
2. In your main build.gradle, set your compileSkdVersion to at least version 28.
3. Avoid AndroidX by setting in your pubspec.yaml the following  plugin dependencies versions:

   android_alarm_manager: 0.2.3

   android_intent: 0.2.1

   battery: 0.3.0

   camera: 0.2.9+1

   cloud_firestore: 0.8.2+3

   cloud_functions: 0.0.5

   connectivity: 0.3.2

   device_info: 0.3.0

   firebase_admob: 0.7.0

   firebase_analytics: 1.1.0

   firebase_auth: 0.7.0

   firebase_core: 0.2.5+1

   firebase_database: 1.0.5

   firebase_dynamic_links: 0.1.1

   firebase_messaging: 2.1.0

   firebase_ml_vision: 0.2.1

   firebase_performance: 0.0.8+1

   firebase_remote_config: 0.0.6+1

   firebase_storage: 1.0.4

   google_maps_flutter: 0.1.0

   google_sign_in: 3.2.4

   image_picker: 0.4.12+1

   local_auth: 0.3.1

   package_info: 0.3.2+1

   path_provider: 0.4.1

   quick_actions: 0.2.2

   sensors: 0.3.5

   share: 0.5.3

   shared_preferences: 0.4.3

   url_launcher: 4.1.0+1

   video_player: 0.9.0

   webview_flutter: 0.2.0
4. Save your changes.
5. If you are using Android Studio, while keeping your pubspec.yaml open, click on the menu Tools -> Flutter -> Flutter Packages Get.  Otherwise, you can use the command line in your project directory and type "flutter packages get".

I hope this helps you fix the error.